# Search API requirements

Tags: search

I'm trying to get the Search API module to work on my Drupal 7 installation, but I get the following error when I go to Home » Administration » Configuration » Search and metadata » Search API » Default node index:

> The server this index currently lies on doesn't support facets. To use facets you will have to move this index to a server supporting this feature.

What steps should I follow, in order to make my server compatible with the Search API module?

Comment: What search server are you using (MySQL Solr etc)?

Comment: i'm using mysql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use facets on MySQL (for the moment), from the project page:

> #### Search facets
>
> This module provides the ability to create facets on any search executed anywhere in Drupal, be it a search page, a view or any other source. The feature isn't available for all servers, though, since it would be too complex to implement for some service classes. Right now **only the Solr servers** support this, facet support for the database-based searches might be done in the future.

This means that you can't use facets, but you can still use Search API to search your content.

Comment: oh so i need to install solr that's all ?

Comment: is it ok if i install apache-solr-1.4.1.zip ?

Comment: @matthewL What is described as "Solr server" is Apache Solr. It runs as Java servlet, and it requires a server like Tomcat, or other similar servers that runs as servlet container.

Comment: unfortunately i get same error even tho i sucessfully configured sorl, and apache solr module is configured perfectly and can communicate with solr on port 8080... not sure what to do now

Comment: @matthewL Did you install and enable the [Search API Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) module? Did you copy the schema.xml and solrconfig.xml to the Apache Solr folder? Did you restart Solr one that was done?

Comment: yes, and then i configured the solr port and site on drupal, and it gave green message that it connected sucessfully.

Comment: one more thing, if i go configuration, search api, settings, edit (drop down), settings > on server there is no option to choose from, it says <No Server>, and when i installed drupal i had only one option for sql server (sqllite) not the mysql server that i had configured

Comment: @matthewL Did you create the Solr server in the Search API interface?

Comment: @matthewL I just tested and you don't actually need Solr to setup the search index. You will need it to actually index the content. What you are missing is to create the server in the interfacer which is just an URL for a Solr server. You do this by clicking the add new server button.

Comment: i clicked Add Server in `config/search/search_api/add_server` and Service class is empty `<Choose a service class>`

Comment: @matthewL Then you are missing the search_api_solr module

Comment: yes, this fixed it!

Comment: ok maybe i dont see the bigger  picture  here , i had apache solr modules installed... hmm is there a overview of the whole installation procedure or other docs i should read? thanks again for help with this issue

Comment: There's a tonne of SOLR guides on the internet, google. This would be a good starting read https://drupal.org/node/504574